# React Native some style causes view to not render

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Hi i am a newbie in React Native, and trying to create an android app using the same. If i change the style of my view -> (backgroundColor or borrderBottom) it just doesn't render. There is no error anywhere, but on reloading the js bundle, the view and all its children fail to render. More than solving this particular issue, i am more interested in understanding why is this happening or whether i am missing something. My component in its entirety is below

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, PixelRatio, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const styles = {
  container: {
    paddingTop: 70,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  form: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  rowContainer: {
    //backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 44,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  inputLabel: {
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    color: '#333'
  },
  textInputStyle: {
    fontSize: 15,
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15
  }
};

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Inside Container </Text>
      <View style={styles.form}>
        <Text> Inside Form </Text>
        <View style={styles.rowContainer} >
          <Text> Inside Row Container </Text>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.inputLabel}> Bid On </Text>
            <TextInput />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The above code works perfectly and all the components are rendered, however if i change the `rowContainer` style and uncomment `backgroundColor`, `rowContainer` and all its children are not rendered. I have no clue why this is happening. I also tried other styles inside rowContainer like

```
rowContainer: {

   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: 'column',
   backgroundColor: '#000'
   borderBottomWidth: 1,
   borderColor: '#c8c7cc'
  }
```

As long as `rowContainer` style is empty it works, if i add anything inside it, the view simply doesn't render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Text color is black and the rowContainers backgroundColor is set to '#000'. So it appears as not being rendered.